# Visual consistancy in mobile

Tags: mobile, web-app, consistency, grouped-list

I'm working in a mobile version of a webapp suite (30 modules). It's a enterprise context.
So, i've tried to create a different approach of the web. And i got this doubt:

**The visual consistency (Modules VS Types) for different contexts (Execute a task VS Start a workflow) is good or it can be a false cognate and confuse the users?**

[Contexts http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/da47538750ea1cef817bf5a57b9908b3.png](http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/da47538750ea1cef817bf5a57b9908b3.png)

Comment: Perhaps me being daft, but I find it really hard to understand what is being asked here. Could you please elaborate and clarify? What consistency are you referring to? That of the interface (collapse panels, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

An analogy first: A pig looks different than a horse. They have different uses and characteristics, and seeing them we instantly set our minds to their specific context. A mule and a donkey look similar, but they have very different abilities and uses. If you could make a mule and a donkey from scratch, wouldn't you make them look more different than they are currently?

With regard to your UI, the headers can probably stay the same, because the words communicate context. However, it is probably best to make a workflow look different than an operation.

Make them look different because:

1. If workflows and operations ever appear in the same view, you will have solved the cognitive issue in advance.
2. the visual difference will set the user's thinking to a completely different context, which is what you want.